# Change button back color based on value in MS Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to make a hotel management system using MS Access as the database. I was able to create log in, registration, checkin, check out forms but I'm trying something new to me.

In my MS Access database I have a table named `rooms` and inside of it are `Roomnumber`("number" that consist of the following: 201,202,203)
 `Roomtype` (short text that consist of the following: Standard,Double,Family)
and `Status`(short text that consist of the following: Available,Occupied,Reserved).

In my form I have buttons named `btn201`, `btn202` and `btn203`.

I want my button back color to change depending on database the value.

Example:

```
If the Status of Roomnumber "201" is "available" btn201 backcolor = green
If the Status of Roomnumber "201" is "Occupied" btn201 backcolor = red
```

Here's my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Homepageform

Dim provider As String
Dim datafile As String
Dim connString As String
Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection

Private Sub Homepageform_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


 provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="

    'access location
    datafile = "C:\Users\RM\Desktop\GPSinVS\GuestProSystem\GuestProSystem\guestprosystemdatabase.accdb"
    connString = provider & datafile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString


    myConnection.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select  [Roomnumber],[Status] FROM [rooms]", myConnection)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

        Select Case row("Roomnumber").ToString()

            Case "201"
                Select Case row("Status").ToString().ToLower()

                    Case "Available"
                        btn201.BackColor = Color.Green

                    Case "Occupied"
                        btn201.BackColor = Color.Red

                    Case Else
                        btn201.BackColor = Color.Black

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                End Select
        End Select
    Next
    myConnection.Close()

End Sub
```

Edit.

I have implemented the code based on @Bugs' answer.

There is no error but `btn201` back color becomes black however in my MS Access database `Roomnumber=201` and `Status=Available` so it should be green.

I have tried removing `Case Else` and running it but no change in color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I prefer using a `DataTable` to work with my data so my code will be leaning towards a solution based on that.

First I would change you `SELECT` statement to not use the wildcard `*`. This is bad practice. Instead specific the columns you wish to include. I would also remove the filter:

```
"Select [Roomnumber], [Roomtype], [Status],  FROM [rooms]"
```

We can now look at getting this data into a `DataTable` and looping through the `Rows` collection:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

    Select Case row("Roomnumber").ToString()

        Case "201"
            Select Case row("Status").ToString().ToLower()

                Case "available"
                    btn201.BackColour = Color.Green

                Case "occupied"
                    btn201.BackColour = Color.Red

            End Select

        Case "202"
            Select Case row("Status").ToString().ToLower()

                Case "available"
                    btn202.BackColour = Color.Green

                Case "occupied"
                    btn202.BackColour = Color.Red

            End Select

    End Select

Next
```

I would use constants for "available" and "occupied" and use those constants in the `Case` statement.

The downside to this is that the statements could get longer and longer depending on how many buttons you have. There may be an alternative way to managing this but hopefully this should help.

Comment: `Case "available"` not `Case "Available"`. I do this `ToString().ToLower()`. Note the use of `.ToLower()`. I do this so that we don't have to worry about the caps. @sid

Comment: Also I am unsure why you are calling `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` That bit of code is not required there. @sid

Comment: Oh my! so i can use .ToLower even if in my database MS Access the first letter of my Status = "Available" is in higher case. i thought i only have to copy whats in my database... anyway it worked!!! Thank you so much! @Bugs

Comment: `.ToLower` will set any value to all lower case. The opposite would be `.ToUpper`. You can use these on `String` values. I do it so I don't have to worry about caps. For example the value could have been "AvailAble" and if you were checking for "Available" you'd never hit that. By explicitly setting the value to lower case I no longer need to worry about that. @sid